# (Belgian) payment providers for both credit cards and Bankcontact/Maestro

Tags: online-payment

I am not certain whether this question is suitable for this SE because I am looking for a service, and one which is specific for Belgium, but here goes.

Here in Belgium not many people use credit cards, especially for online payments. There are other payment solutions, like Bankcontact and Maestro (debit cards) which are prefered. I am currently using Stripe in a solution, and I'm very happy with their API, but they only have support for credit cards, not the other payment methods.

Obviously this results in a much smaller offset market (which is only Belgium anyhow), so I am looking for a decent solution which also offers those. I have looked at Ogone as a solution, but they look like a pain to integrate.

Ideally I want a solution comparable to the API of Stripe, and their Stripe.js library, which enables me to have the user send me a "Stripe validation code" (after they sent their actual credentials to Stripe, not to me), and I only have to use the Stripe API to do the final verification.

I am currently building the application I want to use it from in Spring MVC, also using Spring Boot and Spring JPA

Comment: Contact Stripe and put this to them - it's a business opportunity for them.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll be waiting a looooong time then.